# bash assign a value to variable if environment variable is set in a single line

Tags: bash

How do set a variable value to something based on an environment variable is set.

For example, I want it to be

```
var1 = var2 if ENV_VARIABLE==true else var3
```

(using python syntax for simplicity)

I want this to happen in a single line as well. What is the correct syntax in this case in bash. The guide at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts is good but does not cover this case.

Comment: What's so special about a single line command?

Comment: will be easy to use in other places like makefile and gitlab ci config(for my specific use case)

Comment: What constitutes `true` in your mind in a shell script (rather than Python)?  Is it the string `t`, `r`, `u`, `e`, or the value `1`, or anything that isn't an empty string or … what?  One more or less literal transliteration of `if ENV_VARIABLE==true` is `if [ "$ENV_VARIABLE" = "true" ]`; there are many other possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[[ "$ENV_VARIABLE" == "true" ]] && var1="$var2" || var1="$var3"
```

Comment: Why a numeric comparison (`-eq` is for numbers in shell; it's for strings in Perl) with a non-numeric value `true`?  Or does the `[[` special-case that, too?

Comment: its true, better == for strings

Answer (score 3):

This is portable to ur-`sh` and technically possible to put on a single line.

```
case $ENV_VARIABLE in true) var1=var2;; *) var1=var3;; esac
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var1 = var2 if ENV_VARIABLE==true else var3
```

So:

```
var2=smth
var3="other smth"
ENV_VARIABLE=true
```

we can (the best, does not remove trailing newlines):

```
if [ "$ENV_VARIABLE" = true ]; then var1=$var2; else var1=$var3; fi
```

or (assuming `ENV_VARIABLE` is a string "true" or a string "false" only):

```
if "$ENV_VARIABLE"; then var1=$var2; else var1=$var3; fi
```

or (removes trailing newlines)

```
var1=$(if "$ENV_VARIABLE"; then echo "$var2"; else echo "$var3"; fi)
```

or (removes trailing newlines)

```
var1=$("$ENV_VARIABLE" && echo "$var2" || echo "$var3")
```

or (removes trailing newlines and eval is evil)

```
var1=$(eval echo "\$$("$ENV_VARIABLE" && echo var2 || echo var3)")
```

or (eval is evil)

```
eval var1=\$$(arr[0]=var2; arr[1]=var3; [ "$ENV_VARIABLE" = true ]; echo "${arr[$?]}")
```

or (eval is evil)

```
eval var1=\$$("$ENV_VARIABLE" && echo var2 || echo var3)
```

or (removes trailing newlines)

```
printf -v var1 "%s" "$("$ENV_VARIABLE" && echo "$var2" || echo "$var3")"
```

or (crazy)

```
var1=$("$ENV_VARIABLE"; printf "%s\x00" "$var2" "$var3" | head -z -n$(($?+1)) | tail -z -n1 | tr -d '\000')
```

or (named reference variable, so not really assignment, more a pointer)

```
declare -n var1=$("$ENV_VARIABLE" && echo "var2" || echo "var3")
```

Puff, out of ideas. I honesty think that only the first one is the proper one. I sometimes in my scripts use booleans variables as `true` and `false` strings, which allows for removing only the `[ ... = true ]` parts.

Comment: Many of these are horrible, and should come with more detailed and explicit warnings.

Comment: The first (`if`/`then`/`else`) alternative is probably neatest.  I'd probably quote the variables on the RHS of the assignments.  The rest are an impressive tour de force of possible alternatives, but they should all be left unused in comparison with the first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I usually write quotes in assignments anyway, but word splitting is not performed on assignments, so you can get away without quotes.

Answer (score 3):

`if` statement can be written on a single line.

`-z` can be used to test if a variable is defined and has a value.

`-a` in the test, stands for `AND`

**== EDIT ==**

(see remark from @tripleee: the first version contains a `-a` which is not reliable. I did not found an issue with the first version proposed, but it seems to be a good practice to avoid the use `-a` and `-o`)

Give a try to this:

```
if [[ ! -z "${ENV_VARIABLE}" && "${ENV_VARIABLE}" = true ]] ; then var1="${var2}"; else var1="${var3}"; fi
```

.

.

**== FIRST VERSION ==**

```
if [ ! -z "${ENV_VARIABLE}" -a "${ENV_VARIABLE}" = true ] ; then var1="${var2}"; else var1="${var3}"; fi
```

Comment: `-a` works in Bash, but isn't portable. Maybe switch to `[[` ... `]]` to hopefully remove any illusion that this is portable to other shells.

Comment: @tripleee: super thx, How to determine what is portable and what is not? I mean. I was using `-a` in the 90's in `sh` so it has been a long time, I would have expected it was portable (because old).

Comment: In practice, through practice. For this particular question I quickly found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57840/posix-test-and-a which suggests that it doesn't work reliably with arbitrary arguments in Bash either.

Comment: Waou: I never encountered the issue described in this page. Interesting + thx again!.

Comment: @tripleee: I edited my answer. I did not found any issue with the first version: but it is only by chance as I did not know this reliability issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use default and alternate values together.

```
var1=${ENV_VARIABLE:+$var2} var1=${var1:-$var3}
```

---

```
$ var2=foo
$ var3=bar
$ var1=${ENV_VARIABLE:+$var2} var1=${var1:-$var3}
$ echo $var1
bar
$ 
$ var1=${HOME:+$var2} var1=${var1:-$var3}
$ echo $var1
foo
```